# AspectJ: How to replace an existing annotation

Tags: java, junit, aop, aspectj

Using AspectJ, how do you replace an existing annotation?

I have the following code

```
declare @method : @Test * *(..) : @Test(timeout=10);
```

Which generates the following error on every test method:

```
... already has an annotation of type org.junit.Test, cannot add a second
instance [Xlint:elementAlreadyAnnotated]
```

Of course, the error makes sense but what is the syntax to say, "remove the `@Test` annotation from all methods that have it.  Then replace it with `@Test(timeout=10)`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the AspectJ project lead.  Under https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=313026 we are looking at how to use declare annotation for:

- augmenting existing annotations (adding values to those that are already there)
- replacing them
- defining precedence (should your declare replace what is there?)

We are also looking at a form of it that removes annotations:

declare @remove_from_method: int mymethod(): @ToBeRemoved;

But you can't do it yet...

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've logged in added some votes on the bug. I would love that feature. It feels like creating a work-around is a fairly ugly process.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you can do that with AspectJ. At least I could not find any relevant info in the current version of [AspectJ in Action](http://www.manning.com/laddad/).

What you *can* do is inject your own custom annotation next to the test annotation and write a custom JUnit [`Runner`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/Runner.html) class (bound with the [`@RunWith`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html) annotation, which you can again inject with your aspect) that gives your custom annotation precedence over the `@Test` annotation.

Comment: Funny, that's the same book I have open on my desk, right now. lol. I like where you're going with this.  I've written a few mixins so I'm somewhat comfortable with making classes do completely different things (like extend something else). One problem with your suggestion though: my test classes already use the @RunWith annotation.  I wonder if this could work if I make all tests extend a parent class that uses a custom @RunWith, as you mentioned

Comment: The parent class approach will work (`@RunWith` is marked with `@Inherited`), but if the child classes contain the annotation, the child annotation wins over the parent annotation.